# How to clone anaconda environment to another Windows 10 PC?

Tags: python, anaconda

How to clone anaconda environment to another Windows 10 PC? Or maybe how to export all the packages then I will install these packages in another PC?

I exported a yml file like this:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

How to create a new environment from this yml file? Where do I save this yml file when creating a new enviroment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recommended way is **to create the environment.yml file,   manually**. and this is quite easy!

Have a look at the conda official documentation for [manually creating the environment file.](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment)

and then you can [easily create the above environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) on other window pc by following these instructions.

Hopes that help!

Comment: Thank you Nouman, for creating a new enviroment, I saw this line: conda env create -f environment.yml,  what is the environment name? do I need to add name? or does it create exact same name? Thanks

Comment: @roudan
when creating the environment **file** manually, you specify the name of the that environment in the first line.